# How to get Json object when status 401 Unauthorized using retrofit in android

Tags: javascript, android, json, retrofit2

I Developing android app, I used retrofit 2 API for getting server response. I am getting server response successful. I am getting json object when status code 200k. I am not getting json object body when status code 401 Unauthorized.

```html
 response.enqueue(new Callback<LoginDTO>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<LoginDTO> call, Response<LoginDTO> response) {
            LoginDTO resp = response.body();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
          Log.d("Login Details : ", "Resp is : "+resp);
          Toast.makeText(Signup.this, ""+resp.getMessage(),          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.d("Login Details : ", "Responce is : "+resp.getMessage());
          }
          else if (response.code() == 401) {
          Log.d("response1 hhhhhhhh : ",response.message());
                                } 
                            }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<LoginDTO> call, Throwable t) {
         Log.d("Login Details : ","failed");
                            }
                        });
```

```html
{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Email is already Existed."
}
```

Comment: Are you authorized, when you send response?

Comment: If Email are already in data base I sent 401 request When  Doing Registration process.  I am getting response.message() == Unauthorised. I need to display message data in given object .